# Inserted tikz picture is too small

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics, size, resize

## Problem

I have created a network diagram that shows the behavior of hubs using tikz. When inserting the picture into the side margin of the kaobook class, the picture is way to small. I have tried making it bigger by scaling it in \includegraphics, however it does not change anything. I have also tried scaling the tikz picture environment, however once it reaches a certain size it does not show up in the margin.

## Resources

### Class

[kaobook class - Latex template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook)

[Kaobook class - Github](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook)

### Vector Network Topology Images

[Cisco Network Icons](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/brand-center/network-topology-icons.html)

## Documents

### Main.tex

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% kaobook
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (4/1/2020)
%
% This template originates from:
% https://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% For the latest template development version and to make contributions:
% https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook
%
% Authors:
% Federico Marotta (federicomarotta@mail.com)
% Based on the doctoral thesis of Ken Arroyo Ohori (https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/ken/en)
% and on the Tufte-LaTeX class.
% Modified for LaTeX Templates by Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC0 1.0 Universal (see included MANIFEST.md file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, % Base font size
    twoside=false, % Use different layouts for even and odd pages (in particular, if twoside=true, the margin column will be always on the outside)
    %open=any, % If twoside=true, uncomment this to force new chapters to start on any page, not only on right (odd) pages
    %chapterprefix=true, % Uncomment to use the word "Chapter" before chapter numbers everywhere they appear
    %chapterentrydots=true, % Uncomment to output dots from the chapter name to the page number in the table of contents
    numbers=noenddot, % Comment to output dots after chapter numbers; the most common values for this option are: enddot, noenddot and auto (see the KOMAScript documentation for an in-depth explanation)
    %draft=true, % If uncommented, rulers will be added in the header and footer
    %overfullrule=true, % If uncommented, overly long lines will be marked by a black box; useful for correcting spacing problems
]{kaobook}

% Set the language
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes} % English quotes

% Load packages for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe} % Uncomment to show boxes around the text area, margin, header and footer
%\usepackage{showlabels} % Uncomment to output the content of \label commands to the document where they are used

% Load the bibliography package
\usepackage{styles/kaobiblio}
\addbibresource{main.bib} % Bibliography file

% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments. NOTE: choose only one between 'mdftheorems' and 'plaintheorems'.
\usepackage{styles/mdftheorems}
%\usepackage{styles/plaintheorems}

\graphicspath{{examples/documentation/images/}{images/}} % Paths in which to look for images

\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc] % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the index

\makeglossaries % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the glossary

\makenomenclature % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the nomenclature

% Reset sidenote counter at chapters
%\counterwithin*{sidenote}{chapter}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BOOK INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\titlehead{TeX Exchange Example}
%\subject{This document will help you pass Network+}

\title[TeX Exchange Example]{TeX Exchange Example}
\subtitle{Help Needed}

\author[nescafegold]{nescafegold \thanks{A LaTeX Lover}}

\date{\today}

\publishers{Publisher: Myself}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter % Denotes the start of the pre-document content, uses roman numerals

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OPENING PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\makeatletter
%\extratitle{
%   % In the title page, the title is vspaced by 9.5\baselineskip
%   \vspace*{9\baselineskip}
%   \vspace*{\parskip}
%   \begin{center}
%       % In the title page, \huge is set after the komafont for title
%       \usekomafont{title}\huge\@title
%   \end{center}
%}
%\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\uppertitleback{\@titlehead} % Header

\lowertitleback{
    \textbf{Disclaimer}\\
    You can edit this page to suit your needs. For instance, here we have a no copyright statement, a colophon and some other information. This page is based on the corresponding page of Ken Arroyo Ohori's thesis, with minimal changes.
    
    \medskip
    
    \textbf{No copyright}\\
    \cczero\ This book is released into the public domain using the CC0 code. To the extent possible under law, I waive all copyright and related or neighbouring rights to this work.
    
    To view a copy of the CC0 code, visit: \\\url{http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/}
    
    \medskip
    
    \textbf{Colophon} \\
    This document was typeset with the help of \href{https://sourceforge.net/projects/koma-script/}{\KOMAScript} and \href{https://www.latex-project.org/}{\LaTeX} using the \href{https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/}{kaobook} class.
    
    The source code of this book is available at:\\\url{https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook}
    
    (You are welcome to contribute!)
    
    \medskip
    
    \textbf{Publisher} \\
    First printed in May 2019 by \@publishers
}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\dedication{
    The harmony of the world is made manifest in Form and Number, and the heart and soul and all the poetry of Natural Philosophy are embodied in the concept of mathematical beauty.\\
    \flushright -- D'Arcy Wentworth Thompson
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OUTPUT TITLE PAGE AND PREVIOUS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Note that \maketitle outputs the pages before here

% If twoside=false, \uppertitleback and \lowertitleback are not printed
% To overcome this issue, we set twoside=semi just before printing the title pages, and set it back to false just after the title pages
\KOMAoptions{twoside=semi}
\maketitle
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PREFACE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\input{chapters/preface.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS & LIST OF FIGURES/TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup % Local scope for the following commands

% Define the style for the TOC, LOF, and LOT
%\setstretch{1} % Uncomment to modify line spacing in the ToC
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} % Uncomment to set the colour of links in the ToC
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm} % Manually adjust the height of the ToC pages

% Turn on compatibility mode for the etoc package
\etocstandarddisplaystyle % "toc display" as if etoc was not loaded
\etocstandardlines % toc lines as if etoc was not loaded

\tableofcontents % Output the table of contents

\listoffigures % Output the list of figures

% Comment both of the following lines to have the LOF and the LOT on different pages
\let\cleardoublepage\bigskip
\let\clearpage\bigskip

\listoftables % Output the list of tables

\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN BODY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Denotes the start of the main document content, resets page numbering and uses arabic numbers
\setchapterstyle{kao} % Choose the default chapter heading style

\blindtext

\begin{marginfigure}[-5.5cm]
  \includegraphics[scale=2]{../images/hubs.pdf}
    \caption[hub]{Client and Server relationship Example Using a Web Browser and Web Server}
  \labfig{marginhub}
\end{marginfigure}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
%\pagelayout{wide} % No margins
%\addpart{Class Options, Commands and Environments}
%\pagelayout{margin} % Restore margins

%\input{chapters/options.tex}
%\input{chapters/textnotes.tex}
%\input{chapters/figsntabs.tex}
%\input{chapters/references.tex}

%\pagelayout{wide} % No margins
%\addpart{Design and Additional Features}
%\pagelayout{margin} % Restore margins

%\input{chapters/layout.tex}
%\input{chapters/mathematics.tex}

%\appendix % From here onwards, chapters are numbered with letters, as is the appendix convention

%\pagelayout{wide} % No margins
%\addpart{Appendix}
%\pagelayout{margin} % Restore margins

%\input{chapters/appendix.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\backmatter % Denotes the end of the main document content
%\setchapterstyle{plain} % Output plain chapters from this point onwards

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The bibliography needs to be compiled with biber using your LaTeX editor, or on the command line with 'biber main' from the template directory

\defbibnote{bibnote}{Here are the references in citation order.\par\bigskip} % Prepend this text to the bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=Bibliography, prenote=bibnote] % Add the bibliography heading to the ToC, set the title of the bibliography and output the bibliography note

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NOMENCLATURE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%% The nomenclature needs to be compiled on the command line with 'makeindex main.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o main.nls' from the template directory

%\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
%\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

%\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation} % Rename the default 'Nomenclature'
%\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The next list describes several symbols that will be later used within the body of the document.} % Prepend this text to the nomenclature

%\printnomenclature % Output the nomenclature

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GREEK ALPHABET
%   Originally from https://gitlab.com/jim.hefferon/linear-algebra
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\vspace{1cm}

%{\usekomafont{chapter}Greek Letters with Pronounciation} \\[2ex]
%\begin{center}
%   \newcommand{\pronounced}[1]{\hspace*{.2em}\small\textit{#1}}
%   \begin{tabular}{l l @{\hspace*{3em}} l l}
%       \toprule
%       Character & Name & Character & Name \\ 
%       \midrule
%       $\alpha$ & alpha \pronounced{AL-fuh} & $\nu$ & nu \pronounced{NEW} \\
%       $\beta$ & beta \pronounced{BAY-tuh} & $\xi$, $\Xi$ & xi \pronounced{KSIGH} \\ 
%       $\gamma$, $\Gamma$ & gamma \pronounced{GAM-muh} & o & omicron \pronounced{OM-uh-CRON} \\
%       $\delta$, $\Delta$ & delta \pronounced{DEL-tuh} & $\pi$, $\Pi$ & pi \pronounced{PIE} \\
%       $\epsilon$ & epsilon \pronounced{EP-suh-lon} & $\rho$ & rho \pronounced{ROW} \\
%       $\zeta$ & zeta \pronounced{ZAY-tuh} & $\sigma$, $\Sigma$ & sigma \pronounced{SIG-muh} \\
%       $\eta$ & eta \pronounced{AY-tuh} & $\tau$ & tau \pronounced{TOW (as in cow)} \\
%       $\theta$, $\Theta$ & theta \pronounced{THAY-tuh} & $\upsilon$, $\Upsilon$ & upsilon \pronounced{OOP-suh-LON} \\
%       $\iota$ & iota \pronounced{eye-OH-tuh} & $\phi$, $\Phi$ & phi \pronounced{FEE, or FI (as in hi)} \\
%       $\kappa$ & kappa \pronounced{KAP-uh} & $\chi$ & chi \pronounced{KI (as in hi)} \\
%       $\lambda$, $\Lambda$ & lambda \pronounced{LAM-duh} & $\psi$, $\Psi$ & psi \pronounced{SIGH, or PSIGH} \\
%       $\mu$ & mu \pronounced{MEW} & $\omega$, $\Omega$ & omega \pronounced{oh-MAY-guh} \\
%       \bottomrule
%   \end{tabular} \\[1.5ex]
%   Capitals shown are the ones that differ from Roman capitals.
%\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GLOSSARY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%% The glossary needs to be compiled on the command line with 'makeglossaries main' from the template directory

%\newglossaryentry{computer}{
%   name=computer,
%   description={is a programmable machine that receives input, stores and manipulates data, and provides output in a useful format}
%}

%% Glossary entries (used in text with e.g. \acrfull{fpsLabel} or \acrshort{fpsLabel})
%\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fpsLabel}{FPS}{Frame per Second}
%\newacronym[longplural={Tables of Contents}]{tocLabel}{TOC}{Table of Contents}

%\setglossarystyle{listgroup} % Set the style of the glossary (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary for a reference)
%\printglossary[title=Special Terms, toctitle=List of Terms] % Output the glossary, 'title' is the chapter heading for the glossary, toctitle is the table of contents heading

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%% The index needs to be compiled on the command line with 'makeindex main' from the template directory

%\printindex % Output the index

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BACK COVER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%% If you have a PDF/image file that you want to use as a back cover, uncomment the following lines

%%\clearpage
%%\thispagestyle{empty}
%%\null%
%%\clearpage
%%\includepdf{cover-back.pdf}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

### hub.tex - Tikz

Excuse the terrible code, it is my first tikz drawing (any suggestions on improving is welcome however not relevant to the question).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, transform shape]

% Network Equipment
  \node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{\tiny{hub}}] (hub) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{small-hub.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{\tiny{PC-2}}] (pc) at (2.5,3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=4pt, label=below:{\tiny{Server}}] (server) at (-2.6,-3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{server.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=below:{\tiny{PC-3}}] (pc-2) at (2.5,-3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{\tiny{PC-1}}] (pc-3) at (-2.5,3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};

% Ethernet Cables
\draw[-, thick] (pc) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (pc-2) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (pc-3) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (server) -- (hub);

% Key
\draw (-1.6,5.4) rectangle (1.4,4.5);

\node[text width=3cm] at (1.2,5.2) {\tiny{KEY:}};

\node[text width=3cm] at (0.8,5.0) {\tiny{Ethernet Cable}};
\draw[thick] (-1.5,5.0) -- (-0.8,5.0);

\node[text width=3cm] at (0.8,4.7) {\tiny{Information Travel}};
\draw[red, dashed] (-1.5,4.7) -- (-0.8,4.7);


\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.north east) -- (pc.south);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.north west) -- (pc-3.south);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.south east) -- (pc-2.north);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (server.north) -- (hub.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## End Result

### Main.tex

[image: Example Main Document]

### hubs.pdf

[image: Example tikz drawing]

Any Help is greatly Appreciated

## Solution

Thank you to everyone that answered, changing the class to \documentclass{standalone} instead of article (as per Torbjørn T.'s suggestion) fixed the cropping so it fit perfectly around the image. This resulted in the picture being much more enlarged when inserted to the document.

Here is the result:

[image: tikz-solution]

Besides the changing of the document class to \documentclass{standalone} I also made the text a bit bigger so it is easier to read. I will probably make further changes to the sizes and spacing to make it a bit bigger, as changing the scale still does nothing. Here is the tikz code if anyone is interested.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, transform shape]

% Network Equipment
  \node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{hub}] (hub) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{small-hub.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{PC-2}] (pc) at (2.5,3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=4pt, label=below:{Server}] (server) at (-2.6,-3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{server.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=below:{PC-3}] (pc-2) at (2.5,-3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};
\node[inner sep=2pt, label=above:{PC-1}] (pc-3) at (-2.5,3)
    {\includegraphics[scale=1]{pc.pdf}};

% Ethernet Cables
\draw[-, thick] (pc) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (pc-2) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (pc-3) -- (hub);
\draw[-, thick] (server) -- (hub);

% Key
\draw (-1.6,5.5) rectangle (2.3,4.5);

\node[text width=3cm] at (1.2,5.3) {\large{KEY:}};

\node[text width=3cm] at (0.8,5.0) {Ethernet Cable};
\draw[thick] (-1.5,5.0) -- (-0.8,5.0);

\node[text width=3cm] at (0.8,4.7) {Information Travel};
\draw[red, dashed] (-1.5,4.7) -- (-0.8,4.7);


\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.north east) -- (pc.south);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.north west) -- (pc-3.south);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (hub.south east) -- (pc-2.north);
\draw[->, red, dashed] (server.north) -- (hub.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Guess: try using `\documentclass{standalone}` instead of `\documentclass{article}` in `hubs.tex`.

Comment: What you show as `hubs.pdf` is not what you get as `hubs.pdf`, it's a cropped version of an A4 (or letter) page. And this page is what is included with `\includegraphis` command. Following Torbjørn T. suggestion, you can replace `article` by `standalone` and will get a page with margins adjusted to its contents. Another option which I don't suggest could be to play with ` bb` and `clip` includegraphics options to take only the figure from your A4 page.

Comment: Thank you so much, this cropped it around the image perfectly and greatly increased the size